# Adding restriction(enumeration) on type with attribute

Tags: xsd

im having problems with restricting type with attribute. It looks like this(i can't change it).

```
<xsd:complexType name="TypeWithAttr" abstract="true">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

I need it to restriction so that it can only take 2 values. I have tried doing it like that

```
<xsd:complexType name="TypeWithAttrRestriction">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="TypeWithAttr">
                <xsd:enumeration value="Green"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Blue"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

But it says that i can't have enumeration under restriction.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to restrict the content that contains a text-only, you should use : `simpleContent` instead of `complexContent`. 
some thing like this should work:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="TypeWithAttrRestriction">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="TypeWithAttr">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Green"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Blue"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```